# Ion-menu - registerAnimation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Does anybody has experience with registerAnimation within Ion-menu? I try to add new animations to the menu, like the documentation explains here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/3c9ed3166d3a11a4172b5875784c0321311cfd82/core/src/components/menu-controller

I can’t really show any code, because I couldn’t make anything worthwhile yet.
Any example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for you, although almost 1 year later... hopefully it can be of help.

Here is a "simple" example, using **Ionic 5.0.0-beta.5** (I think it could work with previous versions but the syntax might vary). Let's say I want to speed up the default "reveal" animation. I copied the original animation code from `@ionic/core/dist/collection/utils/menu-controller/animations/reveal.js` and changed the duration to 150ms:

```
import { AnimationBuilder, createAnimation, MenuI } from '@ionic/core';

export const fastReveal: AnimationBuilder = (menu: MenuI) => {
  const openedX = menu.width * (menu.isEndSide ? -1 : 1);
  const contentOpen = createAnimation()
    .addElement(menu.contentEl as Element)
    .fromTo('transform', 'translateX(0px)', 'translateX(' + openedX + 'px)');
  return createAnimation()
    .duration(150)
    .addAnimation(contentOpen);
};
```

Then, in the `app.component.ts` constructor:

```
menuController.registerAnimation('fast-reveal', fastReveal);
```

by importing `menuController` from `@ionic/core` and `fastReveal` from above.

And the final and most important point is to add the **CSS classes** that would have been automatically added if the type was 'reveal':

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu class="menu-type-reveal" contentId="main-content" type="fast-reveal">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">
      Hello !
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" class="menu-content-reveal"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```